# Laravel testing assertJsonMissing does not work for only key. why?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, tdd

I'm working on a tdd project where I simply want to make sure that the password is not returned by mistake. here is the test I wrote.

```
public function testInfoMethodJsonStructure() {
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this
        ->actingAs($user)
        ->get('/api/profile/info');

    $response->assertStatus(200);

    $response->assertJsonStructure(['name', 'fullname', 'email']);

    $response->assertJsonMissing(['password']); // this passes
    $response->assertJsonMissing(['password' => $user->password]); // this does not pass
}
```

I know for a fact that password is being returned but why does the assertJsonMissing does not work when I only pass the key? if it's not used for that, what is the correct way to check that a data key is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assertJsonMissing(array $data)` tries to find `$data` whithin the json you returned.

The difference between `assertJsonMissing(['password'])` and `assertJsonMissing(['password' => 'something'])` is the following:

- `assertJsonMissing(['password'])` tries to find `{"0": "password"}` in your json if the json returned is an object.
- `assertJsonMissing(['password' => 'something'])` tries to find `{"password": "something"}` inside the returned json object.

Here are a couple of alternatives.

- `assertJsonMissingPath('password')`.
- Fluent json assertions.

```php
$response
    ->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
        $json->hasAll(['name', 'fullname', 'email'])
            ->missing('password')
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `assertJsonMissing` is for test key, not value!
You can make a special method for this problem or maybe see this:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#assert-json-fragment